# Dúvidas sobre HTML/CSS - Página Spotify

Tags: html, css, front-end

Estou recriando a Home do Spotify seguindo um curso que peguei na Net e ao continuar sozinho o restante do site em que no curso ainda não tinha, há partes em que ando tendo dificuldades.

Marquei em vermelho na imagem a parte em que não sei como se faz (/mês)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: seja bem vindo, evite nas perguntas colocar "boa tarde", "estou apredendo", etc..seja bem direto, o conceito aqui é pergunta/resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira bem simples, utilizando basicamente dos elementos do HTML é utilizar a tag [`sub`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sub.asp).

```css
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: Indigo;
  padding: 10px;
}

span sub {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: SkyBlue;
}
```

```html
<span>R$0,00<sub>/mês</sub></span>
```